# How to i change the color of my buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i change color of the "Enter"and "more info" button Here is my script:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new select element 

     $('<select>').attr({'name':'select-choice-1','id':'select-choice-1','data-native-menu':'false'}).appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
     $('<select>').attr({'name':'select-choice-2','id':'select-choice-2','data-native-menu':'false'}).appendTo('[data-role="content"]');

    $('<option>').html('More info').appendTo('#select-choice-2');
    $('<option>').html('Enter').appendTo('#select-choice-1');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'1'}).html('Instructions').appendTo('#select-choice-2');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'2'}).html('Bookings').appendTo('#select-choice-2'); 
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'3'}).html('Newsletter').appendTo('#select-choice-2');     
    // Enhance new select element
    $('select').selectmenu();

    $(document).on('change', '#select-choice-2', function(){    
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());


    });    

});
```

would really appropriate the help

Comment: Where are the buttons?

Comment: your jquery looks broken too, are you using any other javascript libraries?

Comment: More info and enter are my buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **THIS** page's console and you will turn the "Post Your Answer" button's color...

```
$("#submit-button").css('background-color','red');   


$(document).on('change', '#select-choice-2', function(){    
  alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
  $("THIS-IS-WHERE-YOUR-HOOK-GOES").css('background-color','red');
});
```

Your hook could be many things, here are several examples.

based on CSS class: ".button-color"
based on ID: "#my-button"
based on ELEMENT: ":button"

Comment: What didn't work? You have to change the #EnterButton to YOUR ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning to <'option'>, create a class and assign to class name like this:

`$( ".button" ).append( "what you want" );`

Then in your css you can change the styles of your button, like the background color:

```
.button{
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Or just add the class to `<option>` and change the styles in your css.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use following `CSS` hope this will help you.

```
#select-choice-1 option:first-child, #select-choice-2 option:first-child {
     color: red;
}
```